# Does a local alternative to WSUS exist?

Tags: windows-10, updates, offline-files, wsus

I've been researching on Google for the question in title, but haven't found much of use except one program called "WUMT" for an alternative to the built in windows update itself.

Here is what I'd like to do:
I have a limited LTE internet data cap on my phone that I tether to my PC for internet and I have one Windows 10 Pro PC, I would like to buy and install Windows 10 Pro for another system but because of my limited internet data cap, I don't want to download the same updates twice and a domain with Windows server is out of the question.

Here is what I'd like to do:
A program to download updates and save locally (possibly WUMT mite work for this)
To make windows update look for updates on my local network (which is an offline wifi router network for media & NAS)
One PC downloads updates & other Windows 10 PC's searches for new updates locally.

There is the Windows 10 feature to share updates to local PC's but unsure if that would work offline.

I am a PC tech so I usually have new installs of Windows now and then and can't be using all my internet data on updates.

Comment: I would try the option to get updates from local PC's on your network and see what happens.  Obviously you'll have to download them *once*, but after that, the other PC's should just get updates from the first PC.  There might be nominal traffic to the internet to grab metadata but I wouldn't expect it to be a lot.  However, if you're making test PC's with various configurations, it's possible they might need updates that don't exist on your primary PC.  So then they might need some updates straight from Microsoft.

Comment: Why aren’t you able to use WSUS? There are other offline methods of updating windows too. It has become difficult to keep Windows 10 from downloading updates online, so you really have to be careful with which combination of settings you use. Using WSUS by itself is no longer sufficient to keep Windows 10 from downloading updates online. And Microsoft keeps changing the rules and settings with every major version of Windows 10.

Comment: I'll try the share to local PC's setting again as I may have gotten some settings wrong the first time. As far as I know in order to use WSUS you need Windows Server which is not affordable. There is the option to use a program like WUMT to download updates and install them to another PC manually but I'm wondering if there is an auto (WSUS like) way of doing it, unfortunately Microsoft don't make it easy for people on a data cap :-(

Comment: If you’re a tech, you might be interested in Microsoft’s Action Pack subscription. Thousands of dollars in cloud and on-premise licensing for around $500/yr. it’s NFR.

Comment: A humble hobby tech at home for very small home use :-)

Comment: Did you know the WUDO feature in Windows 10?Windows Update Delivery Optimization works by letting you get Windows updates and Microsoft Store apps from sources in addition to Microsoft, like other PCs on your local network, or PCs on the Internet that are downloading the same files. It use P2P and will not use much bandwidth.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply, yes I'm going to try the "other PCs on your local network" and see if it works but just not sure if it will work offline. :-)